# Apache poi populate the cell value by formula

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am new to apache poi trying to  write the excel file I am facing some issue while setting the formula to cell.

Below is my sample excel:

| User | Country | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rohit | UK |  |
| John | IND |  |

I need to populate the ***Value*** column based on the on the ***User*** and ***Country*** fields. Below is the excel formula which I want to convert to apache poi java

```
=IF(AND(LEN([@[User]]) > 0, [@Country] = "UK"),1,0)
```

can anybody help me ?

sample code

```
try {
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (inputStream);
        System.out.println("inside the controller");
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Object[][] bookData = {
                {"Rohit","UK",null},
                {"John","IND",null}                   
        };

        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int count=0;
        //CellStyle cell1;
        for (Object[] aBook : bookData) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

            int columnCount = 0;

            Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
            // cell.setCellValue(rowCount);

            for (Object field : aBook) {
                cell = row.createCell(columnCount++);
                if(field==null){
                    cell.setCellFormula("IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)=UK),1,0)"); 
                }
                else if (field instanceof String) {
                  cell.setCellValue((String) field);
                } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
                }
            }
        }

       java.util.List<XSSFTable> l = sheet.getTables();
        l.get(0).getCTTable().setRef("A1:L4");

       FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D://demo/sample_with_values.xlsx");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And please share your code then we can help you.

Comment: I was tried to write the above excel formula  like below in java apache poi
cell.setCellFormula("IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)==UK),1,0)");

error is 
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Parse error near char 25 '=' in specified formula 'IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)==UK),1,0)'. Expected cell ref or constant literal

Comment: The formula in your question uses structured references which only are possible in Excel **tables** (not in default sheets). Please show how you are creating the table in Excel using `apache poi` and how you are trying to set that formula using `Cell.setCellFormula`. In other words: Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The formula `=IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)==UK),1,0)` will not even work in Excel because of the double ==.

Comment: @Axel Richter added the code

Comment: What is in `sample.xlsx` before running the code? Is the first worksheet a default sheet or is there a table defined already? Can you upload  `sample.xlsx` somewhere? If not, do at least describing the initial content of first sheet in `sample.xlsx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `@Axel Richter` mentioned using `==` is invalid.

`cell.setCellFormula("IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)==UK),1,0)");`

Mistakes with your formula.

**#1.** The error...

```
Parse error near char 25 '=' in specified formula 'IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)==UK),1,0)'. Expected cell ref or constant literal`
```

…implies that you are using an additional `=` in the formula.

**#2.** `(B1:B3)==UK` should be `(B1:B3)="UK"`. You are comparing a String value so it should be in double quotes.

**Code**:

```
cell.setCellFormula("IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)=\"UK\"),1,0)");
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("example");

    HSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow((short) 0);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("User");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Country");
    row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Value");

    row = spreadsheet.createRow((short) 1);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Rohit");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("UK");
    row.createCell(2).setCellFormula("IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)=\"UK\"),1,0)");

    row = spreadsheet.createRow((short) 2);
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue("John");
    row.createCell(1).setCellValue("IND");
    row.createCell(2).setCellFormula("IF(AND(LEN(A1:A3)>0,(B1:B3)=\"UK\"),1,0)");

    FileOutputStream out = 
            new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("/Users/anand.keshri/workspace/poi/first.xls")
                    );
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    workbook.close();
    System.out.println("first.xls written successfully");
```